# Level curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I am looking at the following exercise:

State an analogue of Theorem 1.5.1 for level curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $f(x, y, z) = g(x, y, z) = 0$.

The Theorem 1.5.1 is the following:

[image]

So, is the analogue for level curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as follows?

Let $f(x, y,z)$ and $g(x,y,z)$ be two smooth functions of three variables. 
Assume that, at every point of the level curve
$$C = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid  f(x, y, z)=g(x,y,z)=0\}$$ 
$\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ are not simultaneously zero. 
If $p$ is a point of $C$, with coordinates $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$, say, there is a regular parametrized curve $\gamma (t)$, defined on an open interval containing $0$, such that $\gamma$ passes through $p$ when $t = 0$ and $\gamma (t)$ is contained in $C$ for all $t$.

Or is it in this case somehow different?

Comment: It's not sufficient to assume $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ are not simultaneously zero. For example, with $f(x,y,z) = g(x,y,z) = x$, neither $\nabla f$ nor $\nabla g$ is zero anywhere, but their common level set is a plane, not a curve. You have to add a stronger hypothesis. (Hint: think about the case where $f$ and $g$ are linear maps: what does linear algebra tell you about their common kernel?)

Comment: So do we have to require that $\nabla f=\nabla g \neq 0$ everywhere ? @JackLee

Comment: That's exactly what's satisfied in my counterexample: $\nabla f = \nabla g = (1,0,0) \ne 0$.  Did you mean to say $\nabla f \ne \nabla g$?  That won't do either, because you might just have $f(x,y,z)=x$ and $g(x,y,z) = 2x$. Again, think about the linear-algebra analogue.

Comment: The kernel of these maps is the set points at which the map is zero, right? Could you explain to me why at the example of your first comment the level set is a plane and not a curve? I got stuck right now... @JackLee

Comment: It's just the set where $x=0$.

Comment: And to be a curve should $x$, $y$ and $z$ be valued? @JackLee

Comment: So we want that if $f_x=0$ then $g_x \neq 0$, if $f_y=0$ then $g_y \neq 0$ and if $f_z=0$ then $g_z \neq 0$ and inverse the $f$ and $g$. Is this correct? @JackLee

Comment: To get this restriction do we maybe require that $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ are never equal to $0$ ? @JackLee

Answer (score 1):

In general, $C$ won't be a regular curve without imposing some extra conditions. For example, if $f = g$, then generically $C$ will be a surface. Even if $f = 0$ and $g = 0$ are two different surfaces, their intersection can be singular as demonstrated in the following image (taken from Wikipedia):

[image]

A popular condition that forces the intersection to be a regular curve is to require that the surfaces intersect **transversely** in $p$. The technical requirement is that $\nabla_f|_p$ and $\nabla_g|_p$ must be linearly independent. This means that the tangent planes to $f = 0$ and $g = 0$ at $p$ are not the same and so the surfaces are not tangent to each other at $p$. An inverse function theorem argument then shows that locally, around $p$, the intersection $C$ is the image of a regular curve.

Comment: Could you explain to me why the surfaces have to intersect transversely in $p$ so that the intersection is a regular curve?

Comment: The intersection of two planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ passing through the same point will be a plane or a line. It will be a line if and only if the normal vectors to the planes are linearly independent. This is the local linear algebra picture and so one can hope that by imposing this condition on the tangent planes to the surfaces at the intersection point one will get locally a curve and indeed the proof shows that this is the case.

Comment: Why does the following stand? I got stuck right now... $$$$ "It will be a line if and only if the normal vectors to the planes are linearly independent."

Comment: The equation of a plane passing through the origin with normal vector $w_1 \neq 0$ is $P_{w_1} = \{ v \in \mathbb{R}^3 \, | \, \left<v, w_1\right> = 0 \}$. You have $P_{w_1} \cap P_{w_2} = \{ v \in \mathbb{R}^3 \, | \, \left< v, w_1 \right> = \left< v, w_2 \right> = 0 \}$. If $w_1$ and $w_2$ are linearly independent, the equations $\left< v, w_1 \right>$ and $\left< v, w_2 \right>$ are linearly independent so their solution space is one-dimensional.